# JSESSIONID cookie has '.node0' postfix while the server side sessionID doesn't

Tags: java, cookies, jetty, shiro

I am using shiro for session management. When I get the sessionID in server side it is something like this:

```
node0sicwaberf0z59o8qpehfpasf6
```

However, when I check the JSESSIONID in my browser this value is saved as:

```
node0sicwaberf0z59o8qpehfpasf6.node0
```

What exactly is this .node0 and why is this appended to the end of sessionID

It is also worth mentioning that I am using jetty 9 as my web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the Jetty session id (9.3 and onwards) is worker name (e.g. node0), a randomly generated unique ID (e.g. 123x0dsf) and the .worker name (e.g. .node0) according to `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager`.

Check `DefaultSessionIdManager#renewSessionId` and `DefaultSessionIdManager#getExtendedId`.

Answer (score 2):

Session management received a significant overhaul in Jetty 9.4. 
I faced same issue when I upgraded jetty from 9.3.25.x to 9.4.15.x. Due to addition of worker name in JSESSIONID, in my application some header validation that happens outside of Jetty start failing. 
As i have only single node of jetty, i choose to remove node id from session ID. 
I managed to remove `.node` postfix by adding following lines to `start.ini`

```
jetty.sessionIdManager.workerName=
etc/sessions/id-manager.xml
```

By default, Jetty 9.4.x will instantiate a single instance of the DefaultSessionIdManager and HouseKeeper at startup with default settings. Above configuration overwrites workerName in default configuration.

[Reference](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-configuration-housekeeper.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but maybe it will help somebody.

I'm using maven-jetty-plugin (9.4.6.v20170531), end experience similar issue - `Session.getId()` returns one value, but ServletContainer actionally set `JSESSIONID` cookie to `value+'.node0'`.

I do not use clustering in any way, and no configuration at all. This is default behaviour of jetty server.

I managed to remove `.node` postfix by adding following lines to `jetty-env.xml`:

```
<Get name="sessionHandler">
  <Call name="getServer" id="srv"></Call>
  <Set name="sessionIdManager">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager">
        <Arg><Ref refid="srv" /></Arg> 
        <Set name="workerName" type="String"></Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Get>
```

Here is related [source code of DefaultSessionIdManager](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.6.v20170531/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/DefaultSessionIdManager.java#L253)

Answer (score 0):

This is a jetty session id, you can read a little more about it here:
http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/Some-questions-regarding-upgrade-9-3-gt-9-4-td4966096.html